# How to query for records created by an array of users in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Let's say I used CloudKit's discovery feature to get an array of CKDiscoveredUserInfo. From this I can get an array of CKRecordID objects that represent the userRecordID of each of the discovered users.

I want to query a record type for all CKRecord objects created by these users.

What would the code look like to perform this query?  Would it require creation of a predicate that involves creatorUserRecordID or is a different approach required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to create an array of CKReference object like this:

```
var records:[CKReference] = []
```

Then in the callback add the CKReference objects for the users with code like this:

```
for user in users {
    records.add(CKReference(recordID: user.userRecordID, action: CKReferenceAction.DeleteSelf))
}
```

Then you can create a predicate for a query like this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "creatorUserRecordID in %@", records)
```

Comment: IN operator is good for testing list membership according to CKQuery class reference, awesome

Comment: Swift: For me it worked when I removed the brackets [ ] on records, with them it gave me a predicate error

Comment: you can only query on creatorUserRecordID if you have the metadata set to queryable in your dashboard. It is on by default. Record>YourRecordType>Meta Indexes> dropdown

Comment: I'm having trouble using CKReference, and I don't use userID's. I am trying to combine posts from numerous groups into one big feed (like Social Media). Would someone mind looking at the question I just posted about this? Thanks